# Rails 3.1 acts_as_tree - determine children? on FormBuilder object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to figure out how to best do this. I need to drill down recursively through an acts_as_tree model (MenuHeader below). I have the following models:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_headers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :menu_headers
end

class MenuHeader < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu
  acts_as_tree :parent_id
  has_many :menu_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :menu_items
end

class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_header
  has_one :price
end
```

I'd like to loop through all of the menu_headers in a nested manner such that:

```
menu-1
  menu_header -1
      menu_item - 1
      menu_item - 2
    menu_header -2
        menu_item - 3
        menu_item - 4
  menu_header -3
      menu_item - 5
    menu_header - 4
      menu_header - 5
          menu_item - 6
          menu_item - 7
```

and the actual form (see ### for question)

```
<%= form_for(@menu) do |f| %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.text_field :content %><br />
    <%= f.fields_for :menu_headers do |mh| %>
      <%=mh.text_field :name %><br />
      <%= mh.fields_for :menu_items do |mi| %>
        <%= mi.text_field :name %><br />
      <% end %>
  <% ### wtf? - the next section should include the above frag in a partial %>
      <% if fields_for :children? %>
          <%= partial 'children' %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How should I do the wft part above? I need to check if there are children on the FormBuilder object (I think). First time doing something like this in Rails.

thx

**EDIT #1**
looks like something like this is part of it (but not nearly the whole part):

```
<%  if mh.object.children.exists? %>
    <%= render :partial => 'children' %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT #2**
So I'm getting a duplicate rendering of one of the children. I've included what's happening below

should be (menu headers indented 2 spaces, menu items 4 spaces):

```
menu 1
  mh 1, parent_id=nil
      mi 1 - fk menu_header 1
  mh 2 - parent_id=nil
      mi2 - fk menu_header_id=2
      mi3 - fk menu_header_id=2
    mh 3 parent_id=2 
        mi 4, menu_header_id=3
    mh 4 parent_id=2 
      mh 5 parent_id=4
        mi 5, menu_header_id=5
      mh 6 parent_id=5
```

getting with form values in parents - the second menu header #4 is being duplicated

```
menu 1 - menu[content]
mh 1, parent_id=nil - menu[menu_header_attributes][0][name]
    mi 1 - fk menu_header 1 - menu[menu_headers_attributes][0][menu_items_attributes][0][name]
mh 2 - parent_id=nil - menu[menu_headers_attributes][1][name]
    mi2 - fk menu_header_id=2 - menu[menu_headers_attributes][1][menu_items_attributes][0][name]
    mi3 - fk menu_header_id=2 - menu[menu_headers_attributes][1][menu_items_attributes][1][name]
  mh 3 parent_id=2 - menu[menu_headers_attributes][1][children_attributes][0][name]
      mi 4, menu_header_id=3 - menu[menu_headers_attributes][1][children_attributes][0][menu_items_attributes][0][name]
  mh 4 parent_id=2 menu[menu_headers_attributes][1][children_attributes][1][name]
    mh 5 parent_id=4 menu[menu_headers_attributes][1][children_attributes][1][children_attributes][0][name]
        mi 5, menu_header_id=5 menu[menu_headers_attributes][1][children_attributes][1][children_attributes][0][menu_items_attributes][0][name]
    mh 6 parent_id=5 menu[menu_headers_attributes][1][children_attributes][1][children_attributes][0][children_attributes][0][name]
  mh 4 parent_id=2 menu[menu_headers_attributes][2][name]
    mh 5 parent_id=4 menu[menu_headers_attributes][2][children_attributes][0][name]
        mi 5, menu_header_id=5 menu[menu_headers_attributes][2][children_attributes][0][menu_items_attributes][0][name]
      mh 6 parent_id=5 menu[menu_headers_attributes][2][children_attributes][0][menu_items_attributes][0][name]
    mh 5 parent_id=4 - menu[menu_headers_attributes][3][name]
        mi 5, menu_header_id=5 - menu[menu_headers_attributes][3][menu_items_attributes][0][name]
      mh 6 parent_id=5 menu[menu_headers_attributes][3][children_attributes][0][name]
```

Looking into what's going on here - it's like the children_attributes are somewhat halfhazard. Any ideas based upon code what is going on? I should mention that the updates take place Hooray!

Comment: Depth-first traversal? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: Is it possible that it's your data? Can you confirm the relations by hand, just to make sure you don't have a duplicate row?

Comment: y - i'm thining you're right - let me just do some verifications and I'll remove the above edit - although was good for me to see how all of this gets named in the form. demistify some of the magic at least. Awesome job - thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, misread that one.

I believe `<%= mh.object.children %>` will give you the collection of direct children, you'd then have to recursively call `<%= mh.object.children %>` on each respective child (in your patial) to get the whole tree.

You could probably `accepts_nested_attributes_for :children` to allow you to set attributes of them.

**EDIT**
How about this approach:

```
<%= form_for(@menu) do |f| %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.text_field :content %><br />
    <%= f.fields_for :menu_headers do |mh| %>
      <%= render :partial => 'menu_headers/form', :object => mh %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`app/views/menu_headers/_form.html.erb`

```
  <%= form.text_field :name %><br />
  <%= form.fields_for :menu_items do |mi| %>
    <%= mi.text_field :name %><br />
  <% end %>

  <%= form.fields_for :children do |mh| %>
     <%= render :partial => 'form', :object => mh %>
  <% end %>
```

and add:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :children` to your `MenuHeader` model.

Comment: I see the mh.object.children issue but not fully getting your answer - a little bit in uncharted territory for me

Comment: Does that make a bit more sense? Edit above

Comment: cool - makes sense (kinda) but there might be something going on with the number of children. it's duplicating some up. - will update with form input values in a sec